# CSS fullscreen background rgba overlay

Tags: html, css, background, overlay, fullscreen

I have a fixed, fullscreen background image that I applied to the html's css, rather than the body. I have a black overlay with lowered opacity that IS in the body's css because it didn't work when i tried

```
background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), url(image.jpg);
```

I tried without the comma too but it didn't help. I've set `height: 100%` to the `body` with the colour overlay and it works, until I scroll down because it's using 100% of the screen height but no further.

The page I'm working on is a gallery with only 1 or 2 portrait/tall images which cause the problem when they stretch down past the screen and the overlay doesn't follow.

If there's no easy fix, could I add some conditional javascript code or something that'd extend the body's height when just those couple images are being viewed?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do would be to create a div that sits on top of the page to create the overlay. See my example in the snippet below.

Basically the `overlay` div is `fixed`, so it stays in it's `top: 0` even when you scroll. As it's height and width are 100%, it constantly fills the screen. You could now set your background on the body again, or where ever you want it.

```css
.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
.content {
  height: 1000px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="content">Text</div>
<div class="content">Text</div>
```